# Use setOnClickListner on Array Adapter in ActionBarSherlock Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-arrayadapter

I want to add setOnClickListner on ArrayAdapter in ActionBarSherlock so that when i click on the item it changes the fragment but the actionbar at the top keep showing the same bar (like as complete layout gets changed except the action bar)

How to add setOnClickListner in this code. Here's the code to one the fragment:

```
    public class DetailsFragment extends SherlockListFragment{

        /** An array of items to display in ArrayList */
        String details_data[] = new String[]{
            "Personal Info",
            "Emergency Contacts",
            "Application Codes",
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            /** Creating array adapter to set data in listview */
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, details_data);

            /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            /** Setting the multiselect choice mode for the listview */
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "but the actionbar at the top keep showing the same bar" => So what do you want to do instead?

Answer (score 1):

A fragment can supply items to the action bar, but the action bar is tied to the activity, not the fragment. If you remove and add another fragment, the action bar will remain the same.